# JS - Display text with animation from left to right

Tags: javascript

How I can display some text when the user scroll down the page with animation from left to right ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's give Google another result:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  document.querySelector(".this").style.left = "" + window.pageYOffset + "px"
}
```

```css
.this {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  left: 0;
}

p {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="this"></div>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
<p>scroll please</p>
```